# How is it possible to centre a form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

How can you centre a form in C#, so it appears in the middle of the screen

Comment: What kind of application? Web based, WPF based, etc.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about where it *starts*, use [`Form.StartPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx):

```
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

If you want to do it at an arbitrary time, you'll need to work out the size of the screen, the size of the form, and calculate it yourself before setting the `Location` property accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the StartPosition property of the form, change it to CenterScreen.

Answer (score 1):

In Winforms, there is a property of a Form control called StartPosition; it's an enumeration, which includes the position "CenterScreen". Use this, and your window will appear, when first created, in the middle of the monitor on which the mouse is currently located.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) property in the designer

Answer (score 0):

Click your form and press `F4` to show the Properties tab, then scroll down to the `StartPosition` property and change the value to `CenterScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be centered at startup, set your form's StartPosition ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx ) to CenterScreen.

If you want it to be centered some other time, you have to use the SystemInformation.WorkingArea class ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.workingarea.aspx ) and perform arithmetic on that like so:

X = (Screen Width - Form Width) / 2

Y = (Screen Height - Form Height) / 2

And then consider what should happen if your form was too big. Setting either or both coordinates to a negative number is poor form, so don't forget that case.